# Providing auto height and width to dialog in jquery UI modal dialog box

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog, lightbox

I am trying to put auto height and width to modal dialog box (provided by jQuery UI). But some how the position of my dialog is getting disturbed. It is not coming in center. Every time I click on the link to open the dialog box, the dialog opens at different position. Could anybody please suggest how to resolve this issue...

Answer (score -1):

u can main

```
div 

{
 margin:0 auto;
}
or
{
 margin:auto auto;
}
```

==========

Othervise u can set a left and top javascript dailog box position set...

thanks
suresh